# How do you create a proper Epoch calendar object in Java?

Tags: java, epoch

I want to create a calendar object that is the epoch date.  What's the 'correct' (if any) way to do it?

```
Date epochDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse("01/01/1970 01:00:00 GMT");
Calendar epochCal;
epochCal.setTime(epochDate);

// or maybe

Calendar epochCal;
epochCal.setTimeInMillis(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'setTimeInMillis()' method would work fine and be easily understood by others. It might also be clearer if you passed it 0 instead of 1. The first method has more line noise and just adds more chances that something can get screwed up in maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH;
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

If at all you need an object referenced by `java.util.Calendar`, you can get the same using this object of `Instant`:

```
// If at all you need a Calendar object, derive it from instant
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(instant.toEpochMilli());
// Verification
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>